# Can you scan a directory for files name between a certain value eg 20.jpg-40.jpg? PHP

Tags: php

As the title says, is there a simpler way to use **scandir** To return values 20.jpg-40.jpg without having to return all the entire directory?

Comment: I believe you need to scan the full dir either way. It's just a matter if you want to strip out the unwanted ones or some other code doing it.

Comment: Nope. Use `glob()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: @delboy1978uk Please show me how glob will do that. I think only glob has a very basic matching pattern. If i recall correct.

Comment: plenty people already answering that, good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no, there is no generic way to return a range of filenames.

Long answer: you could use [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)'s [pattern matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), in your case:

```
foreach (glob("[23][0-9].jpg") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename" . "\n";
}
```

which would return `20.jpg` to `39.jpg`. To also get `40.jpg`, you seem to be out of luck.

The `glob` pattern matching is some kind of regex, but certainly not as powerful as using [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) or writing your own algorithm.

Comment: Awesome. But how in the name does that pattern work with those returns?

Comment: @Loek this is basic pattern matching, see the wikipedia page for more info.

Comment: Thanks this should do it :)

Comment: @BartFriederichs Ah yes, I see. I was confusing capture groups, which made the `[23]` really weird.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had time to answer before but I think this is a better solution as it's customizeable.
I use scandir becuase, either code have have to look at every file there is.
With glob you can create a simple pattern that will probably leave you wishing for a better option.
With scandir I grab them all and filter them myself with for example array_filter.

```
$dir = scandir($path);
$min = 20;
$max = 40;
$type = "jpg";

$output = array_filter($dir, function ($filename) use ($min, $max, $type) {
    $file = pathinfo($filename);
    return ( $file['filename'] >= $min && $file['filename']  <= $max && $file['extension'] = "jpg");
});
```

This is untested code since I type from my phone and don't have anything to test on, but in theory it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Bit hit or miss, depending on who you ask, but [`glob()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) comes to mind.

```
foreach (glob("*20.jpg") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename" . "\n";
}
```

You can use regex as the parameter for glob.

Comment: This will only get "20". Not "21". I believe OP wants that.

Comment: Uhm... that pattern doesn't seem to be what OP wants. I got the question as "I want 20.jpg, 21.jpg... 40.jpg"

Comment: but that would loop from 20.jpg to whatever is left right? so if there is 1000 jpg 1 to 1000 it would loop from 20.jpg to 1000.jpg?

Comment: Yeah, but then you might as well go for a `scandir`, which is something OP explicitely didn't want...